# csv date to remove slashes

Tags: java, csv, user-interface, bufferedreader

this is a follow up question i had on how to use two delimiters for one csv file. I have a csv file that has the following date format.

```
2018/01/25
2018/01/27
```

I need to upload the csv into a mySql table which takes the date as an INT instead of Date or String format.

when I try and upload the csv I get an error message saying that the date column has been truncated.

I think this is due to the '/' in between the date.

The delimiters are handled by the bufferedReader. Here is my code below.

```
  while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
            String line = br.readLine();// br string variable
            String[] rawRow = line.split(",");
            String lastEntry = rawRow[rawRow.length - 1];//this contains the LinkId/branchNo
            String[] properLastEntry = lastEntry.split("/");//this contains the LinkId/branchNo split into two columnms
            String[] oneRow = new String[rawRow.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(rawRow, 0, oneRow, 0, rawRow.length - 1);
            System.arraycopy(properLastEntry, 0, oneRow, oneRow.length - properLastEntry.length, properLastEntry.length);

            model.addRow(new Object[0]);
            model.setValueAt(oneRow[0], row, 0);
            model.setValueAt(oneRow[1], row, 1);
            model.setValueAt(oneRow[2], row, 2);
            model.setValueAt(oneRow[3], row, 3);
            row++;
            }
         br.close();
```

here is my jdbc code.

```
private void SaveData(){
    Connection connect = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try{

        //DriverManager Loader
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //connection string url.. the port//schema name//username//password
                                                //this is the test Server ;oginDetails
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/riskfin", "root", "riskfin"); //-------------> this is for the localhost server
        stmt = connect.createStatement();

        for(int i = 0;i<table.getRowCount();i++)
        {
            String PayDate = table.getValueAt(i,0).toString();
            String Ammount = table.getValueAt(i,1).toString();
            String LinkID = table.getValueAt(i,2).toString();
            String BranchNo = table.getValueAt(i,3).toString();

            String  sql = "Insert into temp_payment_import "
                    +"VALUES('"+LinkID+"','"
                    +Ammount+"','"
                    +PayDate+"','"
                    +BranchNo+"')";

            stmt.execute(sql);
       }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data imported Successfully");

    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        if(stmt!= null){
            stmt.close();
            connect.close();
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Follow-up to what? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511267/loading-csv-into-mysql-table)? If so, put the link in your question, or don't say it's a follow-up.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes its a follow up to that(--this?--) question I had earlier...

Comment: Fortune, the problem is with your JDBC code, not what you posted above in this question.  Show us that code instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I really think the problem is with the slashes, since the table in mysql set the paydate column as an INT, I doubt it takes any other character set except numerical values.

Comment: Why are you trying to insert dates/text dates into an integer column?  Doesn't that strike you as being a bit off?  You should insert those dates into a date column; they are in a format which MySQL can handle.

Comment: it did, but the client insists I use the table they have as is... most of it was designed poorly (being very polite rn..), but I have to do it as the client wants. I had hoped that if the problem would be bypassed by removing the slashes.

Comment: I attempted an answer below which I believe should fix most of your database problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two major problems with your current JDBC code.  First, you are not using prepared statements, increasing the chance that your insert statement will have problems.  Second, you don't explicitly list out the target columns for the insert, also inviting problems.  Consider the following modification:

```
for (int i=0;i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO temp_payment_import "
     + "(PayDate, Amount, LinkID, BranchNo) VALUES "
     + "(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, PayDate);
    ps.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(Ammount));
    ps.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(LinkID));
    ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(BranchNo));
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

While this may not run as is, it is a step in the right direction.  Now, the insert statement lists out the columns explicitly, so there is no chance that you insert the wrong value into a certain column.  Because it seems that all your data is coming as string values, you may have to do a bit of work to obtain a date/timestamp for the pay date.  I used `setString` above, which should actually work if your dates are in an ISO format which MySQL accepts.  But it would be better to use a format date type which JDBC recognizes for dates.

Comment: I get a syntax error when I use the above method, in the '(?,?,?,?)' line.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening.  I would guess that you copied wrongly, or there is some other problem with your code.  Are you _certain_ that you are using a _prepared_ statement, and _not_ a regular statement?

Comment: thanks Tim, I managed to remove the errors, the only problem is that now when I check mysql there is nothing written to table even though it says the import was successful, but thanks again

Comment: That's really strange.  One possibility is that you have auto commit set to false for some reason, and in your code you never explicitly commit the transaction.  That would explain doing all those inserts yet having no actual data in your tables.  There could be other reasons as well.

Comment: thanks Tim I checked and auto commit is set true, Thank you again, I will try and check whats wrong if i fail I will ask it separately.

Comment: when I added a if statement to check if rows were added or not, it brought back the ' Data truncated on column 'paydate' on column 1' error message. and there is a null pointer Exception as well with it .

Comment: Yeah...I mentioned that this might not work.  You need to use `setDate` or `setTimestamp` on the statement with a proper date type, not just plain string text.  Although, I have seen the above work in some cases.

Comment: oneRow[0] = oneRow[0].replaceAll("/","");

Comment: This is a hack.  The better thing to do would be to pay attention to my above comment where I recommend using `Statement#setDate` to directly insert dates into your query.

Comment: Tim I prefer calling it a work around, The column was being truncated because Mysql wanted to read it but could not due to the slashes, I removed the slashes and mysql took the String, I had to change the datatype in the database to LongText so I left it as a String in my java program.